# IAutomation - How retrieve value of argument which passed by pointer?

Tags: c++, com, automation

IAutomation - How retrieve value of argument which passed by pointer?

In .idl file writed:

```
interface IAutomation : IDispatch {
        [id(0x000000e0), helpstring("Returns if the player is ready. Many of the other commands fail as long as the player is not ready.")]
        HRESULT GetReady([out] VARIANT* Ready);
};
```

I suppose, GetReady() - method, not property.

If I trying use VOLE library:

```
object player = object::create("StereoPlayer.Automation", CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, vole::coercion_level::valueCoercion);
VARIANT var;
::VariantInit(&var);
VARIANT pos = player.invoke_method(vole::of_type<VARIANT>(), L"GetReady", var);
```

But recieve linker error:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static struct tagVARIANT __cdecl vole::com_return_traits<struct tagVARIANT>::convert(struct tagVARIANT const &,enum vole::coercion_level::coercion_level)" (?convert@?$com_return_traits@UtagVARIANT@@@vole@@SA?AUtagVARIANT@@ABU3@W4coercion_level@42@@Z) referenced in function "public: struct tagVARIANT __thiscall vole::object::invoke_method<struct tagVARIANT,struct tagVARIANT>(struct vole::of_type<struct tagVARIANT>,unsigned short const *,struct tagVARIANT const &)" (??$invoke_method@UtagVARIANT@@U1@@object@vole@@QAE?AUtagVARIANT@@U?$of_type@UtagVARIANT@@@1@PBGABU2@@Z)
```

Calling other methods, which return nothing, works perfectly.

Also I try directly call method IDispatch::Invoke() as discribed in [How To Use Visual C++ to Access DocumentProperties with Automation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/238393)
. But misunderstood how return value too.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with VOLE, but if I am reading its source code correctly, you need to do this instead:

```
VARIANT pos = player.invoke_method<VARIANT>(L"GetReady");
```

Or this:

```
VARIANT pos = player.invoke_method(vole::of_type<VARIANT>(), L"GetReady");
```

You are trying to pass in a `VARIANT` as an `[in]` parameter to `GetReady()`, but it has no such parameter.  It has an `[out]` parameter instead, which is represented by the return value of `invoke_method()`, so you don't need to pass in your own `VARIANT` parameter.

`invoke_method()` performs `VARIANT`-to-type coersions internally, so assuming `GetReady()` actually returns a boolean value wrapped in a `VARIANT`, you might even be able to do something like this:

```
VARIANT_BOOL ready = player.invoke_method<VARIANT_BOOL>(L"GetReady");
```

Or even:

```
bool ready = player.invoke_method<bool>(L"GetReady");
```

Comment: If call invoke_method without parameter - invoke() return  hr=0x8002000e Invalid number of parameters.